# Delete Lines End and beginning whith :

Tags: arrays, string-matching

I need delete all lines that end with `:`.

List example:

```
name1
name2
name3:
name4
name5:
```

I need convert this to:

```
name1
name2
name4
```

Another example:

```
name1
:name2
name3
:name4
```

Convert to:

```
name1
name3
```

Thanks in Advance :*

Comment: What language/technology? What have you tried?

Comment: @user235867 Welcome to SO. try including attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. Also all proper tags for which language of platform you are using.

Comment: Im so Sory for my english :|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `sed`

```
sed -r '/^:|:$/d' file
```

**EDIT**

If you have leading or trailing spaces in a line, try adding `\s*`

```
sed -r '/^\s*:|:\s*$/d' file
```

Comment: thats not find any thing

Comment: @user235867 please check my EDIT in answer. both works fine for me. If still it doesn't work, please specify your platform and what's the exact output.

Comment: @user235867 are you sure you have lines like what's shown in example? or what kind of list you have?